# How do you install flask-sqlalchemy in a virtual environment while working with Cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin

I use Cygwin terminal on Win7 OS. You can see my python3 and pip3 versions below.

```
(env)
user ~/env
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.10

(env)
user ~/env
$ pip3 --version
pip 21.3.1 from /home/user/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

I was trying to install flask addons and when I hit

```
pip3 install flask flask-sqlalchemy
```

It gives the result below. Could you please name the problem? Also please know that I'm working in a virtual environment.

```
$ pip3 install flask flask-sqlalchemy
Requirement already satisfied: flask in ./lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.2)
Collecting flask-sqlalchemy
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in ./lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask) (8.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in ./lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in ./lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in ./lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask) (3.0.3)
Collecting SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.4.31-cp39-cp39-cygwin_3_3_3_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in ./lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask) (2.0.1)
Collecting greenlet!=0.4.17
  Using cached greenlet-1.1.2.tar.gz (91 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/user/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-2zv1me05
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/
  Complete output (71 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
  copying src/greenlet/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_contextvars.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_cpp.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_extension_interface.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_gc.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator_nested.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_leaks.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_stack_saved.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_throw.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_tracing.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_version.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/test_weakref.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  running egg_info
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
  writing manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/greenlet/greenlet.c -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
  copying src/greenlet/greenlet.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
  copying src/greenlet/slp_platformselect.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_alpha_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_amd64_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_ios.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_csky_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_mips_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_aix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_linux.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_riscv_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_s390_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x32_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.asm -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.obj -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_msvc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_msvc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
  copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension.c -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
  running build_ext
  creating build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/src
  creating build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/src/greenlet
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/home/user/env/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/greenlet/greenlet.c -o build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/src/greenlet/greenlet.o
  In file included from src/greenlet/greenlet.c:11:
  src/greenlet/greenlet.h:8:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      8 | #include <Python.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Running setup.py clean for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
Installing collected packages: greenlet, SQLAlchemy, flask-sqlalchemy
    Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/user/env/bin/python/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-fgk4qhlk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/env/include/site/python3.9/greenlet
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/
    Complete output (73 lines):
    running install
    /home/user/env/bin/python/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
    copying src/greenlet/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
    creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_contextvars.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_cpp.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_extension_interface.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_gc.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator_nested.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_leaks.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_stack_saved.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_throw.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_tracing.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_version.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_weakref.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    running egg_info
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying src/greenlet/greenlet.c -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
    copying src/greenlet/greenlet.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
    copying src/greenlet/slp_platformselect.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet
    creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_alpha_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_amd64_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_ios.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_csky_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_mips_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_aix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_linux.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_riscv_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_s390_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x32_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.asm -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.obj -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_msvc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_msvc.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_unix.h -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension.c -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/greenlet/tests
    running build_ext
    creating build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/src
    creating build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/src/greenlet
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/home/user/env/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/greenlet/greenlet.c -o build/temp.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.9/src/greenlet/greenlet.o
    In file included from src/greenlet/greenlet.c:11:
    src/greenlet/greenlet.h:8:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
        8 | #include <Python.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/user/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ej14c7c/greenlet_611bde6e44b84ce894d7dff8b18c2a96/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-fgk4qhlk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/env/include/site/python3.9/greenlet Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: have you installed `python39-devel` ?

Comment: just installed it and tried again but unfortunately had the same result

Comment: same error ? Strange as `/usr/include/python3.9/Python.h` is there and the compiler should find it with `-I/usr/include/python3.9`

Comment: I checked Cygwin's website and saw the recommendation about "not installing it on C drive". I'll install it on D drive, try again and share the results

Comment: The problem has been solved. I deleted Cygwin from C: and instead installed it on another drive. After hitting the command "pip3 install flask flask-sqlalchemy", Boom! All of the packages were just installed and built. I'm suspecting about there was an issue related to system permissions. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: What drive you install on shouldn't really matter.  However, some things don't work well if you installed Cygwin in a directory with spaces in the name.

Comment: I suspect he\she was not using the default `C:\Cygwin64` but just `C:\`

Comment: No, it was C:\Cygwin64.